# Object doesn't support property or method 'call'

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am learning asp.net core with typescript and angular2, when run the project, there was an error in the browser console：[image: Object doesn't support property or method 'call']Object doesn't support property or method 'call'.

Comment: When you need help, make sure you know what you want to be help with.

Comment: I just want to know how to solve this problem and let my program run

Comment: but what exactly is the problem? We can't figure out much with just a screen shot of a console error. Have you possibly figured out what may be the cause? It can be the dotnet core itself, it could have been webpack not set up properly, it could have been versions of node modules being not compatible. Or it could be the code you have writen. You need to start eliminating the rather improbable causes of the error.

Answer (score 1):

> Object doesn't support property or method 'call'.

Check the stack trace. You most likely have passed a *non* function to something that expects a function.

## More

- Docs on `call` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call